# Getting fatal error when adding array of struct into another array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, structure

In my app i have a struct `PlayerRegistrationModelArray`. In which i have a variable `player` which is the array of another struct `playerArray`. I have created a variable of `PlayerRegistrationModelArray` in `AppDelegate`. But when i am trying to append `playerArray` into player in `PlayerRegistrarionSecondViewController` class i am getting error like:-

> "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

Please help me to solve the following issue.

```
struct PlayerRegistrationModelArray {
    var player: [playerArray]?
}

struct playerArray {
    var playerName: String
    var playerGender: String
    var playerDOB: String
    var playerSports: String
    var playerGrade: String
}




class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var playerInfo: PlayerRegistrationModelArray?
}




class PlayerRegistrarionSecondViewController{

   var playerarr: playerArray?
 var mAppDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


func postAddPlayers(){

   playerarr = playerArray(playerName: name_TextField.text!, playerGender: gender_TextField.text!, playerDOB: dateOfBirth_TextField.text!, playerSports: sport_TextField.text!, playerGrade: grade_TextField.text!)

   var playerData = mAppDelegate.playerInfo?.player
   playerData?.append(playerarr!)
   if playerData!.count > 0 {
      print("DEBUG: playerData Is \(playerData!)")
   }

   for i in playerData! {
      paramters.updateValue(i.playerSports, forKey: "playerinfo[0][player_fullname")

}
}
}
```

When i am printing playerarr:

> DEBUG: player array Is playerArray(playerName: "shy", playerGender:
>   "Male", playerDOB: "1989-05-19", playerSports: "Baseball - 30 minute
>   session", playerGrade: "5")

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: " for i in playerData!  " at this line i am getting error. When i am running the for loop in player data.

Comment: Sorry, but your code is a mess. What you posted does not compile. Please update your code as a [example]. And get rid of all the forced unwrapping.

Comment: Hi @koen, I have updated my code. please look into it. i am not good in formatting stack overflow questions. sorry for the messy code.

Comment: please initialise playerInfo variable in appDelegate ... its nil

Comment: what is result of this line `if playerData!.count > 0 {
      print("DEBUG: playerData Is \(playerData!)")
   }`

Comment: your code is breaking on this line .... firm belief `if playerData!.count > 0 {`

Comment: Hi @jawadAli for  intializing playerInfo i have written the code that you have mentioned earlier -  lazy var playerInfo: PlayerRegistrationModelArray? = PlayerRegistrationModelArray(). is it ok? or any thing i have to write ?

Comment: thats okay and perfect

Comment: check it out now ... it will work..

Comment: Yes, i tried this, but still the playerData is nil. i think the error is "var playerData = info.player".  but when  i tried  var playerData = [playerarr], it works but the first index is nil.

Comment: Hi @jawadAli  i have written   " var playerInfo = [playerArray?]()" in appDelegate and in my "PlayerRegistrarionSecondViewController" i have written 

 var playerData = mAppDelegate.playerInfo
 if let play = playerarr {
     playerData.append(play)
      }  

      This code works for me. But i want to ask is it the correct way to write the code or any thing wrong in it?

Comment: this is perfect way to write sir ....

Comment: you are using appDelegate as singleton class ... more best is to create your own singleton class if you want to share this array between number of controllers...

Comment: i dont know why people downvote without comments ....

Comment: Yes i will try to create my own singletone class. your code is good but i think any thing wrong in my code. i will try to resolve the issue. i will upvote your answer. once again thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks @koen for your time.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help. I highly recommend that you read how to use optionals to avoid these type of errors. And also, please make it a habit to choose meaningful names for your structs and classes. For instance your `struct playerArray` really should be `struct Player`, and `PlayerRegistrationModelArray` is better called `PlayerRegistrationModel` with a `var player: [Player] = []` property.

Comment: @TapanRaut I wrote a small Playground that you can look at with some of my suggestions here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/564h7x0fakyhorg/Players.playground.zip